# My model combines EffcientNetB0 and LSTM with X_train size is (150,150,3), model does not fit…

Tags: python

```
input_shape=(150,150,3)
effnet = EfficientNetB0(weights=None,include_top=False,input_shape=input_shape
effnets=effnet.input_shape#(150,150,3)
Res_model = effnet.output
print(Res_model.shape)                              #(None, 5, 5, 1280)
model = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(Res_model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 1280)
model=  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu")(model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 512)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(model, training=True)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 512)
model = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32,activation='softmax')(model)
print(model.shape)                                  #(None, 32)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=effnet.input, outputs = model)
#print(model.input_shape)                            #(None, 150, 150, 3)
#print(model.output_shape)                           #(None, 32)

#LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# Define the input shape for the sequence data
sequence_input = Input(shape=(150,150))
print(sequence_input.shape)

# Instantiate the LSTM model
lstm_model = LSTM(32)(sequence_input)
print(lstm_model.shape)

# Concatenate the output of the EfficientNetB0 model and the LSTM model
concatenated = Concatenate()([model.output, lstm_model])

# Add a dense layer to the concatenated output
output = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)#input_shape=[(None, 5, 5, 1280), (None, 32)]
# Define the final model
model1 = Model(inputs=(Res_model,sequence_input), outputs=output)
model1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = 'Adam', metrics= ['accuracy'])
history = model1.fit((X_train,y_train), batch_size=32,
                              epochs = 2, validation_split=0.1,verbose=1)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>"})
```

Comment: Hi @MinikaKohli, welcome to the site. At least let us know what "does not fit" specifically means, what you have tried to debug it, if you have tried simplifying it, etc. As a tip, a general technique to debug models is to make them overfit to a single data batch to see if they learn.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: trying to train the model on custom dataset with input images of shape(150,150,3)

Comment: My purpose is to classify data by concatenating two models